# Should I use .Net Core 2.0 or 2.1?

Tags: .net-core

I was wondering:

1. What the difference between the two version of .Net Core were.
2. What version of .Net Core would be best for an intranet application
   and the reason(s).

Thank you!

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/

Comment: Pretty sure MS provides a changelog where you can see all the details on what's new. As for the second question - depends on whether you need features provided by 2.1 or not. The question is rather vague and I'm guessing it will probably be closed soon.

Comment: kevin, if uyou could add some context to the question as to why you would want to choose between the two?

Comment: I needed some input to understand if using 2.0 or 2.1 had certain advantages/disadvantages when creating a simple intranet app that uses a Web Api for login, and saves employee info to a DB. Thanks

Comment: Ok, just use the latest then.

Comment: Great thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend reading the following if you are upgrading from previous versions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-2-0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-2-1

However, as a general rule of thumb I would go for the latest version you can, unless you have a specific reason to go for the older one.

I'd avoid .Net 2.0, its reached end of life as of 1st October 2018.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/06/20/net-core-2-0-will-reach-end-of-life-on-september-1-2018/

Comment: .NET Core 2.0 is a Current release, not a LTS release, so "its LTS finished" is using completely wrong term. You should simply say "its lifecycle".

Comment: Thanks, amended, it has no LTS is what I meant to say.